# Angularjs - using orderby filter in the controller's scope

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui, watch, angularjs-orderby

I have an array of objects i.e. filtered and paged and now I would like to order the list items by different object attributes.

I tried the `orderBy` filter as follows:

```
<th><a href='' ng-click="reverse = sortParam == 'title' && !reverse; sortParam = 'title'">Title</a></th>

<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems|filter:filterParam|orderBy:sortParam:reverse">
    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
</tr>
```

This seems to be working fine, clicking on the `Title` link, orders the row alphabetically or reverse alphabetically depending on the current state.

But the problem here is that only the `pagedItems` are being ordered, which makes sense as we are applying the `orderBy` filter to the `pagedItems`. What I want to achieve is to order the whole set of items (not just currently paged items) to be ordered when the filter is applied.

In order to achieve this I thought i'd use a method in the controller scope. so I changed the above to:

```
/** In the Template */

<th><a href='' ng-click="sortItems('title')">Title</a></th>

<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems|filter:filterParam">
    <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
</tr>


/** In the Controller */

$scope.sortItems = function(value) {
    $scope.filtered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filtered, value);
};

$scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage + filtered', function() {
    $scope.pagedItems = getPagedItems($scope, 'filtered');
});
```

The `sortItems` method works and changes the order but the items in the view does not get updated as the `$watch` code is not fired. I assumed that maybe it's not being changed because the data in the `$scope.filtered` is not being altered and just the indexes are being changed. So I added and empty element at the end of the array:

```
$scope.sortItems = function(value) {
    $scope.filtered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filtered, value);
    $scope.filtered.push({});
};
```

Now, Everything works as expected but I can't keep an empty object in the array as it affects the items, count and data being displayed. So I thought I'd add and remove an empty item. So changed the above to :

```
$scope.sortItems = function(value) {
    $scope.filtered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filtered, value);
    $scope.filtered.push({});
    $scope.filtered.pop();
};
```

But guess what the `$watch` code not being fired again.

**Question**

My question is does `$watch` look for changes in an array based on it's length ? If yes, what is the best possible way to achieve what I'm trying to. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I solved this using `$broadcast` and `$on` as follows:

```
$scope.sortList = function(value) {

    if (value === $scope.currentFilter) {
        value = value.indexOf('-') === 0 ? value.replace("-","") : "-" + value;
    }   

    $scope.currentFilter = value;
    $scope.filtered = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filtered, value);
    $scope.$broadcast('sorted');
}

$scope.$on('sorted', function() {
    $scope.pagedCandidates = getPagedItems($scope, 'filtered');
})
```